# How to style paper-input with certain mixins (polymer 2)?

Tags: css, polymer, mixins, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to style a paper-input based on a design I got. I used some of the custom proprieties described [here](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/elements/paper-input-container) , but not all of them work.

I have problems using **--paper-input-container-label** and **--paper-input-container-input-focus**.

Maybe I try to use them the wrong way or it requires some extra steps.

Here is my code

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../paper-input/paper-input-container.html">
<link rel="import" href="../iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../iron-icon/iron-icon.html">

<dom-module id="first-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      paper-input {
        --paper-input-container-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
        --paper-input-container-focus-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);

        --paper-input-container: {
          border: none;
          padding: 0px;
        }


        --paper-font-subhead: {
          font-size: 100%;
        }

        --paper-input-container-underline-focus: {
          display: none;
        }

        --paper-input-container-underline: {
          display: none;
        }

        --paper-input-container-input: {
          height: 24px;
          line-height: 20px;
          padding: 0 4px;
          border: 1px solid rgb(194, 198, 199);
        }

        --paper-input-container-input-focus: {
          border-color:red;
        }

        --paper-input-container-label {
          font-weight: bold;
        }      

        --paper-input-container-invalid-color: red;
      }

       :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

    <paper-input always-float-label label="Floating label"></paper-input>
    <paper-input label="username">
      <iron-icon icon="icons:accessible" slot="prefix"></iron-icon>
      <div slot="suffix">@email.com</div>
    </paper-input>


  </template>

  <script>
    class FirstElement extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'first-element'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          prop1: {
            type: String,
            value: 'first-element'
          }
        };
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(FirstElement.is, FirstElement);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: What *exact* problems do you have?

Comment: Did you just build your DOM wrong? I've changed the colors to stand out, but see http://plnkr.co/edit/TMeXa7sIyzystv8RI5wb?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what result you are expecting so it is hard to help you, but one thing I am sure it's your style tag is so messy. And you need to write a semi-colon after mixins because they are like css properties and every css properties are semi-colon separated.
Try your code like that :

```
<style>
  :host {
    display: block;
  }

  paper-input {
    --paper-input-container-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
    --paper-input-container-focus-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);

    --paper-input-container: {
      border: none;
      padding: 0px;
    };

    --paper-font-subhead: {
      font-size: 100%;
    };

    --paper-input-container-underline-focus: {
      display: none;
    };

    --paper-input-container-underline: {
      display: none;
    };

    --paper-input-container-input: {
      height: 24px;
      line-height: 20px;
      padding: 0 4px;
      border: 1px solid rgb(194, 198, 199);
    };

    --paper-input-container-input-focus: {
      border-color: red;
    };

    --paper-input-container-label: {
      font-weight: bold;
    };

    --paper-input-container-invalid-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Another thing, you are trying to style the border color of the input on focus but also you are setting `display` to `none` which doesn't make sense. You have to remove `display: none` and add `border-color: red;` to `--paper-input-container-underline-focus` if you want to style the color.

Comment: Thx for the reply. I'm trying to style the input html element, the underline doesn't help me in this case and shouldn't interfere with the input.

I had semicolons  at the end of the proprieties, but the editor I'm using (Visual Studio Code) flagged them as errors, that's why I removed them.

Comment: @sirbushir I don't recall to have had this problem with VS Code, try to disable some options like some linting or html parsers, maybe that is the reason you see them as errors because this syntax is not really part of w3c standards. Also if you are unsatisfied with the design of the input-paper, you shouldn't try to mess with that internal behavior, instead you should make your own custom element and be fully satisfied with yours.

Comment: @sirbushir Your DOM for <paper-input-container> is wrong. See https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/elements/paper-input-container and my Plunker (linked to in comment to your original post). As for the semicolons, I believe they are "required" I don't see that they make a difference in the outcome.

Comment: @Thad Ok I guess you are right for the semicolons, they are "optional" but only for the mixins not for the css variables. Also it is strongly recommended to use them anywhere as for your IDE to properly format the code. I think your Plunker doesn't really help the OP, he is not just asking why is his code not working, I think he wants to color the input frame in red on focus (not color the label in magenta or cyan)